# Webrtc static library on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, webrtc

I am looking for a way to include Webrtc in my iOS project. My project consists some C code which I am looking for a way to call the Webrtc apis from. I am able to do this in Android using a Makefile and linking the webrtc library. However, I haven't been able to do it on iOS. I tried to build a webrtc.framework but I am not sure how to link it to my C code. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The WebRTC.framework that gets created by the build script has Objective-C header files. You cannot call Objective-C methods in a C source code (.c) file. You'll need to consume it in an Objective-C (.m) file or Objective C++ (.mm) file.

Comment: but in Android it I am able to create a staic webrtc library...I want to see if I can do something similar?!

Comment: I'm sure you can, that build is not supported in WebRTC

Answer (score 0):

Google introduced and then quickly decided to drop static library target somewhere in Sep 2018. We usually build static library once a month for ios. I can share libs on github if you like.

Comment: Please share or mention how you would configure and build a static lib

Comment: We plan to publish clear instructions and modified ninja files on github. However, in the meantime if you like to use WebRTC static libraries, please refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899319/weak-linking-a-framework-to-a-static-library/53902279#53902279

Comment: Are these bitcode enabled? I'm finding that building from source with `gn` and `ninja` builds a 419 mb framework. That seems excessive.

Comment: yes bitcode enabled. Bitcode adds quite a bulk to overall size. When you combine for both thearm platforms, it will be 800mb+

Comment: @Mark can u plz share the static library with me.