# Weak linking a framework to a static library

Tags: ios, cocoapods, webrtc, static-libraries

## Problem

My project is arranged like this:

- App

  - Framework

    - Static library (common code)

The static library is going to start depending on the GoogleWebRTC framework. Unfortunately, this dependency can only be built as a framework via [WebRTC.org](https://webrtc.org). They removed the ability to build as a static library for maintenance reasons.

## Question

Is is possble for the static library to weakly link to the GoogleWebRTC framework?

- App

  - Framework

    - Static library ("CommonCode")
  - GoogleWebRTC

Some solutions that come to mind are:

- Including the WebRTC header files in the static library, and build with a custom modulemap so that the `include "<WebRTC/WebRTC.h>` works. Then embedding and linking the library in the App target
- Somehow converting the GoogleWebRTC.framework to a static library and embed the headers and binary in the "CommonCode" static lib
- I... can't remember the other solution I had in mind. I'll update this when I remember.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate decision on Google's part to remove static target.

if that helps, you can use mesibo webrtc framework which is a **static framework** build using **modified ninja files**. Only downside is, it is not as regularly updated as Google build (typically lags by a month old sync).

https://github.com/mesibo/mesibowebrtcframework

All you have to do is to copy `WebRTC.framework/WebRTC` from **mesibo version** which is nothing but a static library, extract using `lipo -extract` and repackage it with your own library using `lipo -create`.

Below is the difference you will see in Mesibo and Google Version of WebRTC framework

Mesibo version

```
$ file WebRTC.framework/WebRTC
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures: [i386:current ar 
archive random library] [arm64]
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture i386):    current ar archive random library
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture x86_64):  current ar archive random library
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture arm64):   current ar archive random library
```

And Google Version

```
$ file WebRTC.framework/WebRTC
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64] [arm64]
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture armv7):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm_v7
WebRTC.framework/WebRTC (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64
```

Let me know if you need more inputs!

Comment: Thanks for the input! However this does not solve my problem. The `WebRTC.framework/WebRTC` file is actually a dynamic library, so I can't combine it with my static library:
`WebRTC is a dynamic library, not added to the static library`

Comment: Have you tried it? mesibo webrtc framework is a special buid from modified ninja files that produces static library. I have updated the original answer to show the difference between both google and mesibo version (last post had files mixed up).

Comment: Thanks so much for updating your answer! It's very thorough! Unfortunately a requirement is to either use the first party library or build from source.

Comment: @yumoji thanks for posting link to github. Unfortunately there is no way to check what webrtc version they used.

Comment: @LeanidVouk it is updated once in a month. Are you looking for some specific version or feature missing in that?

Comment: @yumoji : I had downloaded Webrtc.Framework in 2018 and the webrtc.framework file size was 873Mb file but when I download it now it only shows 148MB. When I create Bindings in C# it is messing up bindings and giving the errors.

Comment: @user2801184 shows 833MB to me, https://github.com/mesibo/mesibowebrtcframework/blob/master/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC

Comment: My LFS was turned off. Thank you for help. Can you please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190672/unable-to-screencast-to-apprtc-using-replay-kit-over-webrtc

Comment: @yumoji: Can you please update the mesibowebrtcframework?

Comment: @yumoji: If not point me to the directions to follow to get the FAT framework for iOS